# Access Javascript object's property inside decleration

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple JavaScript object which have three fields

1. Name
2. FName
3. FullName

What i did is this

```
var xyz = {
          name: 'ahsan',
          fname: 'ashfaq',
          fullname : xyz.name + xyz.fname

      };
```

but its not working .

Comment: If you do not care about old IE, you can use `Object.defineProperty(xyz, "fullname", {get: function(){return this.name+ this.fname;}})`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reference the rug under your feet during inline object creation.  If you really want a property that exhibits this behaviour, then create a class or make the assignment in a separate statement:

```
var xyz = {
      name: 'ahsan',
      fname: 'ashfaq',
      fullname : undefined
   };
xyz.fullname = xyz.name + xyz.fname;
```

Class implementation:

```
function XYZ(o) {
    this.name = o.name;
    this.fname = o.fname;
    this.fullname = o.fname + o.name;
}

var xyz = new XYZ({
        name: 'ahsan',
        fname: 'ashfaq'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making the full name a field, declare it as a method -

```
var xyz = {
    name: 'ahsan',
    fname: 'ashfaq',

    // Declare a method to return the full name
    fullname : function () {
        return this.name + this.fname;
    }
};
```

and then -

```
xyz.fullname();
```

will give you the full name.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9DknH/2/).

You cannot access an object's properties in the same block which defines it. In your example, JavaScript will look for a defined object named `xyz`. Since the object isn't available at this point, you will only get `undefined`.

The scenario changes when you access the properties from a method. Here, you can use `this` to refer to the current object, which is `xyz`. So when you call this method, `this` will refer to `xyz`, and at that point its properties will be defined.

Comment: don't you think it would be better to define why we should do this way . I think it would help future readers .